# SD : No such file

Tags: python, python-import, hdf5, pyhdf

I'm using `pyhdf.SD` to import some hdf5 files to python. I'm able to import one file in a program

```
file=SD(file_path,SDC.READ)
```

But after that, if I import another hdf5 file within the same program, it throws an error `HDF4Error: SD: no such file`.

I tried to reimport the `pyhdf` module after importing a hdf5 file, but the error persists.

What might have caused this?

The file I am dealing with cannot be imported through `h5py` module, so `SD` method seems to be the only way for now.

Comment: The message suggest that the file does not exists. Are you sure that the file path is ok? Are you using a relative path?

Comment: @GonzaloOdiard I had stored the file paths in a list in this format r"folder\file.hdf", this was creating some problem. It has something to do with string formatting and NOT with SD. Thank you.